# How to append a value in the header of xml using oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

Below is my actual header

```
<HEADER ReqNotf="N" TransactionCode="SERVICE_CHANGE" PublisherApplID="CM" PublisherApplThreadID="1" IssueDate="2015-07-15T00:00:00" EffectiveDate="2015-07-15T00:00:00" RoutingId="100107553" DistributionType="SELECTED" BulkTransaction="N" EntityId="100107553" EntityType="CUSTOMER"/>
```

I want below

```
<HEADER ReqNotf="N" TransactionCode="SERVICE_CHANGE" PublisherApplID="CM" PublisherApplThreadID="1" IssueDate="2015-07-15T00:00:00" EffectiveDate="2015-07-15T00:00:00" RoutingId="100107553" DistributionType="SELECTED" BulkTransaction="N" EntityId="100107553" EntityType="CUSTOMER" ErrForBD="Y"/>
```

I have just added `ErrForBD="Y"` at the end of the header.

Please help me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [UpdateXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14214/chapter1.htm#OBJECTIVENO04108) can not insert new attribute.

> The current UpdateXML() function can only manipulate the content of existing nodes within an XML document. It cannot be used to add or remove nodes from a document.

You must use [insertChildXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298666/how-do-i-add-an-attribute-to-xml-contained-within-a-clob-in-an-oracle-database)